Compiling of PDF/A-1B compatible document fails due to LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group
I'm trying to build a PDF/A-1B compatible document of class scrbook.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to build it, due to a strange error that's occurring since I upgraded to MacTeX 2024 (before I was using MacTeX 2022).
I installed MacTeX via Homebrew, if that could be a possible source of problems.
However, I checked all dependencies listed in the log, and they are installed:

pdfx
xmpincl
ifpdf as part of iftex
ifthen as part of latex

The relevant part of the error log:
** pdfx: Metadata file MAIN.xmpdata read successfully.
(./MAIN.xmpdata)

/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty:2746: LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2746  \RequirePackage
                       {xmpincl}
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xmpincl/xmpincl.sty

/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xmpincl/xmpincl.sty:20: LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 \RequirePackage
                    {ifpdf}

/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xmpincl/xmpincl.sty:34: LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 \RequirePackage
                    {ifthen}
)
Using XMP template file: pdfa.xmp


This is a known issue of package pdfx and the author already knows it. Packages never should have been loaded inside a group. Since the last LaTeX kernel update, "never should have been" has changed to "must not be".

@cabohah Oh okay thank you! Then I hope that's being fixed soon. As I was not able to find an issue related to this, could you eventually post an answer referring to that bug report, so that I can close my question :) Thanks!

I cannot find a pdfx issue tracker. But on TeX-Live mailing list Ulrike told, that the pdfx maintainer already has implemented a fix, but currently has not uploaded it to CTAN. So I would ask him via email.

Until pdfx is fixed you can use \RequirePackage[2024-05-01]{latexrelease} at the top of the file if you don't need any features added in the June release.

There is no issue tracker, but there is a mail adress of the maintainer Ross Moore in the documentation.

@DavidCarlisle Where do I have to put the \RequirePackage[]{} command? Placing it at the top of my main file didn't work.

@the_dani as the first line of the file, it will roll back (most) changes in the latex format to how it was at that date, but whether that is enough to make any particular document work is hard to say. If you get errors make a small example and post a new question.

A new release of pdfx is available on CTAN. This release doesn't load package xmpincl in a group. So updating should fix the issue (and here with TeX Live 2024 indeed does).

For me a change of the line \RequirePackage{xmpincl} outside the group do the trick. My code from pdfx.sty from 2738 looks like:
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  2018-12-16:   xmpincl  needs the  ifthen  package
%%  it should be loaded outside the grouping, else  biblatex  may barf
%%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xmpincl}
\begingroup
%% override the \ifpdf  check of  xmpincl  package, inside the grouping
 \pdftrue
%% combine coding from  xmpincl  and  hyperxml to support XeTeX
\def\pdfx@xmpincl@xetex#1{%
 \IfFileExists{#1.xmp}{%
  \mcs@xmpincl@patchFile{#1}%
  \begingroup
   \special{pdf:fstream @pdfx@Metadata (#1.xmpi)
    <<
      /Type /Metadata
      /Subtype /XML
    >>
   }%
   \special{pdf:put @catalog
    <<
      /Metadata @pdfx@Metadata
    >>
   }%
  \endgroup
 }{%
  \newcommand{\mcs@xmpincl@filename}{#1.xmp}%
    \PackageError{xmpincl}%
    {The file \mcs@xmpincl@filename\space was not found}%
    {The file \mcs@xmpincl@filename\space The metadata file
     wasn't found.\MessageBreak Oops.}%
 }
}
\ifxetex
 \let\includexmp\pdfx@xmpincl@xetex
\fi


that will work with pdflatex but probably fail with xelatex. (xelatex is the main reason why pdfx is doing this, xmpincl is old and doesn't properly support xelatex).

works also for lualatex

I can confirm the trick based on moving of \RequirePackage{xmpincl} outside the group.
With xelatex I've had to move also \pdftrue line before \RequirePackage{xmpincl} to prevent warning Package xmpincl Warning: Only pdflatex is supported by the xmpincl package. and consequent ! Undefined control sequence. error:
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  2018-12-16:   xmpincl  needs the  ifthen  package
%%  it should be loaded outside the grouping, else  biblatex  may barf
%%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\pdftrue
\RequirePackage{xmpincl}
\begingroup
%% override the \ifpdf  check of  xmpincl  package, inside the grouping
% \pdftrue
%% combine coding from  xmpincl  and  hyperxml to support XeTeX
\def\pdfx@xmpincl@xetex#1{%
 \IfFileExists{#1.xmp}{%
  \mcs@xmpincl@patchFile{#1}%

