Error: "Loading a class or package in a group. \usepackage" with .cls file
I am writing my thesis with .cls file. This morning, everything worked well, and suddenly, my dumb brain decided to mess around with the MikTeX Console. And of course, I could not compile with the .cls file anymore.
So I decided to reinstall the MikTeX Console. And again, I could not compile the .cls. It gives me this error: "Loading a class or package in a group. \usepackage", like a bunch of them. Other errors are "Loading a class or package in a group. \RequirePackage" At first I thought because I used \usepackage{A,B,C}, so I tried to separate them like \usepackage{A}, \usepackage{B} and so on; but it still did not work. Then I tried to replace all \usepackage with \RequirePackage in the .cls file but it still did not work.
However, when I try to compile from a single .tex file. It works well. It does not give me any errors at all. I only encountered this problem when I compiled it with a .cls file. I use MikTex as the TeX distribution as well.
Here is my log-file until the first error.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.7.23)  23 JUL 2024 10:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Main.tex
(./Main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(./Main.cls
Document Class: Main 2007/22/02 v1.0 LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo
File: bk11.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count194
\c@chapter=\count195
\c@section=\count196
\c@subsection=\count197
\c@subsubsection=\count198
\c@paragraph=\count199
\c@subparagraph=\count266
\c@figure=\count267
\c@table=\count268
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count269
\Gm@cntv=\count270
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count271
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen142
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen146
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen147
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen148
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen149
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2024/06/14 v2.6d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen150
\ar@mcellbox=\box52
\extrarowheight=\dimen151
\NC@list=\toks19
\extratabsurround=\skip51
\backup@length=\skip52
\ar@cellbox=\box53
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2022/12/04 v6.7b set line spacing
)

! LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.142 \usepackage
                 {vmargin}
Classes and packages should only be loaded at the top level

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/vmargin/vmargin.sty
Package: vmargin 2004/07/15 V2.5 set document margins (VK)

Package: vmargin 2004/07/15 V2.5 set document margins (VK)
\PaperWidth=\dimen152
\PaperHeight=\dimen153
)

This is an error related to \RequirePackage
! LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.126 \RequirePackage
                     {amstext}[1995/01/25]
Classes and packages should only be loaded at the top level

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

And here is my part of the preamble in .cls (it is quite lengthy so I only copied up until the last error):
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Main}
[2007/22/02 v1.0
LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}

\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
    \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
    \@tempswafalse
    \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
        \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
        \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
    \let\@this\@empty
    \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\copyrightnotice[1]{
    \btypeout{Copyright notice}
%   \addtotoc{Copyright notice}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\noindent \Huge \bf{Copyright~notice}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    % \cleardoublepage
}


\newcommand\abstract[1]{
    \btypeout{Abstract}
%   \addtotoc{Abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\noindent \Huge \bf{Abstract}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
    \btypeout{Declaration}
%   \addtotoc{Declaration}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\noindent \Huge \bf{Declaration}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\acknowledgement[1]{
    \btypeout{Acknowledgements}
%   \addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\noindent \Huge \bf{Acknowledgements}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\Publicationslist[1]{
    \btypeout{Publications during enrolment}
    \addtotoc{Publications during enrolment}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\bf{Publications~during~enrolment}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\Declarationpublication[1]{
    \btypeout{Thesis including published works declaration}
    \addtotoc{Thesis including published works declaration}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    % \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\bf{Thesis~including~published~works~declaration}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\Preface[1]{
    \btypeout{Preface}
    \addtotoc{Preface}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \null\vfil
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\bf{Preface}}
    %\vskip 60\p@
    {\normalsize #1}
    \vfil\vfil\null
    %\cleardoublepage
}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
    January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
    July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
    \space \number\year}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
\spacing{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\parskip}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.2in}  % left margin
{ 0.8in}  % top margin
{ 1.2in}  % right margin
{ 1in}  % bottom margin
{  20pt}  % head height
{0.25in}  % head sep
{   9pt}  % foot height
{ 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,bbm,mathrsfs,mathtools,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularx,pbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{20pt}{-30pt}{40pt}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
    frame=tb,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
    language=Matlab,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={black},
pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
    \let\\\space
}

In the .tex file, I start off with:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Main} 

I also want to add that this issue only happens with this particular .cls file. I have another .tex file for my separate paper where I start with:
\documentclass[10.5pt]{article}

which did not have any problems at all.

You updated LaTeX, the newest version errors if a package is loaded in a group (which you shouldn't do). Show your preamble and the log-file until the error so that someone can tell you where the problem is and what to do.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720126/compiling-of-pdf-a-1b-compatible-document-fails-due-to-latex-error-loading-a-cl

Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I have read the post and see that pdfx has a new release. I have never done this before. Should I update the package through MikTex Console?

It seems you are using macOS. I wouldn't use miktex there. Distributions like mactex are much more common and better tested.

nothing in your log suggests that you are using pdfx   it looks like you have in your main file { \usepackage{something} } you should not do that.

"Then I tried to replace all \usepackage with \RequirePackage in the .cls file but it still did not work." never edit standard class files such as book.cls you will break your latex installation.

I told you to show your preamble and the log. Why are you doing only half of it?

@DavidCarlisle my crystal ball points to https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/315

@l.ngn as a general rule if you get a tex error reported on your document, the first assumption should be that you have made an error in your document. So it is unlikely to be fixed by re-installing tex or editing standard files, and other people will not be able to tell you how to fix it unless you show the code with the error.

@UlrikeFischer I have added the preamble in the question. Sorry, I was panicking and didn't respond to your reply properly. It worked in the morning of that day, and after I updated my MikTeX, I got this problem. Thank you for being patient with me. I really appreciate it.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your advice; I have added both of the codes and the error message that I got from compiling. I suspect it is because I updated MikTeX (I am not so sure)

remove the \spacing{1.5}. That is wrong. spacing is not a command, but an environment. The correct command would be the one commented a line above. See the hyperref issue https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/315 which errors because of the same wrong command.

@UlrikeFischer you brought back a new Czech crystal ball from Prague?

the class was always in errror, but you benefit from the better error checking in recent latex, so now you get informed of it rather than it silently doing the wrong thing.

@UlrikeFischer omg it worked :(( thank you so much I wanna cry. I wish you were next to me so i could give you a hug and buy you a coffee. Thank you David Carlisle as well, I will keep in mind your advice <3 Thanks both again.

Off-topic: It should be noted that more things in the class are far from ideal. For example, the attempt to use \bf with argument (which only doesn't fail because there is another group that delimits the \bf), or the use of the obsolete package subfigure. IMHO the positions of some \addtotoc and \thispagestyle are also wrong.

There is no need to panic if you get such an error. Simply ask in the right place with sufficient details (here local class and log-file), then such problems can normally be solved in a few minutes.
